# Enable PowerShell remoting on new Azure VM

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-remoting

I've created a new VM in Windows Azure to use to act as a host to learn a bit of Powershell Remoting. After the VM was created I RDP'd onto the box and enabled remoting via the following command:

```
 Enable-PSRemoting
```

I confirmed both prompts with 'a' replies and it finished without errors. If I run

```
  Get-PSSessionConfiguration
```

I can see that three endpoints (?) have been set up. In the Azure portal I can see that the Powershell port is open - both 5986 is open as a public and private port.

I've added the public IP address of the machine to my hosts file, but when I try the following:

```
  Enter-PSSession -ComputerName AZURESERVERNAME
```

I get an error:

> Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server AZURESERVERNAME failed
>   with the following error message : A specified logon session does not
>   exist. It may already have been terminated. For more information, see
>   the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic. At line:1 char:1
>   + Enter-PSSession -ComputerName AZURESERVERNAME
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (AZURESERVERNAME:String) [Enter-PSSession],
>   PSRemotingTransportException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed

I've also tried setting all hosts as trused as follows:

```
  cd wsman::localhost\client
  Set-Item .\TrustedHosts *
  Restart-Service WinRM
```

But that doesn't seemed to have helped either.

Is there anything else I need to do to get this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, figured this out thanks to the awesome [Secrets of Powershell Remoting ebook](http://powershell.org/wp/2012/08/06/ebook-secrets-of-powershell-remoting/). Looks like you must add the machine directly to the TrustedHosts via IP address:

```
Set-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value '11.22.33.44'
```

Then use that IP address *and* specify credentials in the Enter-PSSession:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 11.22.33.44 -Credential 11.22.33.44\username
```

You should then get a prompt for your password and voila! :)

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully created a SharePoint farm in Azure using the scripts from [Automated-Deployment-of-SharePoint-2013-with-Windows-Azure-PowerShell](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools-samples/wiki/Automated-Deployment-of-SharePoint-2013-with-Windows-Azure-PowerShell)

On that page there are steps that configure PowerShell to work with Azure

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy ByPass 

Enable-PSRemoting 

Enable-WSManCredSSP -role client -delegatecomputer "*.cloudapp.net"  

$regKey = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Credssp\PolicyDefaults\AllowFreshCredentialsDomain" 
Set-ItemProperty $regKey -Name WSMan -Value "WSMAN/*.cloudapp.net"  

Get-AzureSubscription -ExtendedDetails
```

You may also need to do this

> Run GPEdit.msc You must also enable delegating of fresh credentials
>   using group policy editor on your client machine. Computer
>   Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Credentials
>   Delegation and then change the state of "Allow Delegating Fresh
>   Credentials with NTLM-only server authentication" to "Enabled." Its
>   default state will say, "Not configured."
>
> In the Add Servers sections add the following.
>
> WSMAN/*.cloudapp.net

Comment: Thanks. Followed through those steps but get the same: Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server AZURESERVERNAME failed with the following error message : A specified logon
session does not exist. It may already have been terminated. For more information, see the
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName AZURESERVERNAME
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (AZURESERVERNAME:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed